# JavaScript hide and then show elements in an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a simple array which has three elements. My elements are holding simple paragraph formatted text:

```
var quoteList = new Array(
"<p>One</p>", 
"<p>Two</p>", 
"<p>Three</p>"
);
```

This initialisation is done in my header. Now, in my body I print them by doing a simple document.write;

```
for(i=0; i<quoteList.length();i++)
{
    document.write(quoteList[i]);
}
```

This works, it prints out my three paragraph formatted text elements held in my array.

Now, I want to scroll through them when a, `<a href>` tag is clicked, but I'm having issues even getting some of my elements showing, and some hiding, see example;

```
quoteList[0].style.display="block";
quoteList[1].style.display="none";
quoteList[2].style.display="none";
```

This doesn't seem to be working. So, I have two issues:

1. Cycling through my array elements on mouseClick
2. I can't even get my quoteList elements hidden / visible.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Sa7af/

Comment: Awww thanks dfsg. I shall keep that as a reference :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`quoteList` is an array of strings. After writing those strings to the document you create HTML elements and need to access them like that.

One solution is to add an id tag in the string phase: `"<p id="p_0">One</p>"` and then accessing it with `document.getElementById("p_0")`.

Another option is creating the elements using `document.createElement("p")` and then appending them to the document. Because you've created the elements you can store them in an array.

A third option is retrieving all `<P>` tags using `document.querySelector("p")` and then iterating through them. Keep in mind that this will select all `<P>` elements in the document.

Comment: AHhh I can't believe I didn't think about adding a tag into my string phase. Should be able to work it all out now, cheers Gil